# Troubles binding when using non sequential indices and having multiple custom type parameters in method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-4.5

Say I am posting back this form:

```
 <form action="/Admin/SaveTestChanges" method="post">

        <input name="index" type="hidden" value="S1"/>

        <input name="[S1].SID" type="hidden" value="1"/>

        <input id="sectionName" name="[S1].SectionName" type="text"  value="Nouns"/>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

To this method:

```
     public void SaveTestChanges(TestModel Test, List<SectionModel> TestSections,
                List<QuestionModel> TestQuestions, List<ChoiceModel> QuestionChoices)
            {
                // Some implementation

            }
```

The object `SectionModel` has unique property names which none of the other custom types in the parameter list have, however upon binding it not only says that `TestSections.Count` is 1, but also says the same for all the other collection types for which there was no key/value pairs passed. Why is this so?

When using non-sequential indices is it possible to include the parameter name as well and not just property names? i.e. `TestSections[S1].SectionName` or `[S1].TestSections.SectionName` ?

Comment: If you use the built-in helpers to generate the input fields, MVC will assign IDs that the default ModelBinder is capable of decoding when the data is posted back to the server. If you wish to use your own naming convention you can write and register your own ModelBinder implementation. Google "MVC custom ModelBinder" for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but appears the default model binder can handle this just fine. All that was needed is to prefix "index" with the actual parameter name.Else the model binder gets confused with so many collections of complex types.

Answer (score 0):

Appears that when using arbitrary indices and storing them in the hidden input you still need to prefix the input name "Index" with the actual parameter name as it appears in the action method.
So in my case the hidden inputs name property should be set to `TestSections.Index`, having just "Index" confuses the model binder and the results can be flawed.